# Sending my bike cover from airport A to airport B // pick-up 9 days later

Tags: airports, spain, bicycles, mail

I would like to ask if it is possible to send a package from one airport (Faro, Portugal) to another airport (Vigo, Spain) with my bike cover and pick it up 9 days later.

I would like to bike 9 days between those 2 countries but the cover is too big. Any advice?

Comment: Just to clarify: you are asking to ship a package to an airport?

Comment: Are you asking about the cover/container in which you put your bike when it's checked as baggage? You're flying into Faro and out of Vigo and need a way to send it between the two locations?

Comment: Yes, Dorothy. That is what I am asking.

Comment: Disagree with the "close as unclear" vote, I see no ambiguity in this question.

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at this, it might just be easier to ship to a hotel instead of a airport.

http://bicycletouringpro.com/what-to-do-with-your-bike-box-case-once-you-reach-your-bike-tours-starting-location/

Scenario 4 is the closest to your situation.

Easiest solution: If you are staying in a hotel at the end of your trip, you can contact that hotel so that you can ship the box there and ask them to store that for you.

Another solution (same web page)
If you want to, you can use a cardbox bike box that you can throw away and buy a new one at the end of your trip.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Spain, but usually delivery companies can only deliver within a certain span of days -- they're not set up as storage companies.

Your best bet is to lug your bike cover/bag to your first hotel and then bribing the concierge or front-desk clerk with a generous tip so that they store your bag for 5-6 days and then send it to the airport B. A local bike shop  might also be willing to do this, again with a generous tip.

More information might be found at bicycling.stackexchange.